# c# how to enable another form

Tags: c#, winforms

i already tried

```
frmMain frm = new frmMain();
frm.Enabled = true;
```

and i found some links

https://ph.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110428083144AAkiWkm

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4ebd5faf-80ac-4b4f-99bc-f11b4ded1483/c-enable-disable-form

neihter one works

Comment: Are you looking for frm.Show() ?

Comment: no I have 2 forms frmMain and frmDeleteaccount.  frmMain is crrently disabled. I want to I enable frmMain using frmDeleaccount.

Comment: Disabled or invisible?

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to enable some other instance of frmMain? In the code above you create a new instance.

Comment: I got it already man.
I have to create an instance of frmMain out side the function.
already did.

Answer (score 0):

As seen on the first link you provided, you have to set the Enabled property of the current form to false and then you have to call the `Show()` method of the form you want to open.

`oldform.Enabled = false;
frmMain frm = new frmMain();
frm.Show();`